# C - make msgrcv coexist with signals

Tags: c, ipc, message-queue

I need some help with msgrcv... I need to be able to receive messages like this:

```
while(1){
    int status = msgrcv(qid, &msg, sizeof(msg.data), user_id,0 )
    if(status < 0) { perror("something wrong..."); exit(1); }
}
```

And also somewhere on the code:

```
void stuff_to_do(int signal){
   //   ....
}
//...
signal(SIGQUIT, stuff_to_do);
```

But I get a Interrupted System Call, probably because the signal kills the msgrcv or something like that. 
How can I solve this? Should i fork() and do the msgrcv in one process and do the stuff on the other process? Or is there a better way?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't try to `fork()` and divide the tasks, that would just complicate things. Whatever process that calls `msgrcv()` can still receive signals and get interrupted.

Comment: @e0k Yes that's true... I thought it would solve it but it won't since I need to stop the while ( 1 ) with a signal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your process receives a signal during `msgrcv()`, it will be interrupted.

From the [man pages on `msgrcv()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/msgrcv):

> The calling process catches a signal. In this case the system call fails with *errno* set to **EINTR**. (**msgrcv**() is never automatically restarted after being interrupted by a signal handler, regardless of the setting of the **SA_RESTART** flag when establishing a signal handler.)

Try to identify this failure condition and just restart `msgrcv()` with something like

```c
while (1) {
    // Try to receive message
    errno = 0;
    int status = msgrcv(qid, &msg, sizeof(msg.data), user_id,0 )

    if (status < 0) {
        if (errno == EINTR) continue;  // try again

        // Something else went wrong
        perror("something wrong...");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Don't forget that you have to manually set `errno = 0` before the operation you want to test.

This reminds me of a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong#answer-26557243) that describes concurrency and simultaneity.  It explains why you have to always use the approach of trying the operation, then check to see if it succeeded.

---

See also:

- [How to handle EINTR (interrupted System Call)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674162/how-to-handle-eintr-interrupted-system-call)
- [msgrcv - SA_RESTART flag doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585075/msgrcv-sa-restart-flag-doesnt-work).

Comment: Thanks alot! I'll test it.